# java 8 lambda - use stream multiple times

Tags: java, lambda

Is it possible to avoid creating stream inside current stream from the same collection like in below example to collect some data (listOfA is used two times to create stream) ?

```
List<A> listOfA = Arrays.asList(new A(1L, "A1", "V1"), new A(2L, "A2", "V1"), new A(1L, "A1", "V2"));

List<B> listOfB = listOfA.stream().map(r -> new B(r.getId(), r.getName(),
            listOfA.stream().filter(r2 -> r.getId().equals(r2.getId())).map(A::getVal).collect(toSet())
    )).distinct().collect(toList());

class A {
     private final Long id;
     private final String name;
     private final String val;

     A(Long id, String name, String val) //constructor
     //getters

}

class B {
     private final Long id;
     private final String name;
     private final Set<String> values;

     B(Long id, String name, Set<String> values) //constructor
     //getters


     @Override
     public boolean equals(Object o) {
          ...
          return id.equals(a.id);
     }
     //hashCode
 }
```

The final result should be a list of 2 objects:

B{id=1, name='A1', values=[V1, V2]}

B{id=2, name='A2', values=[V1]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you question aims at. If the question is what the minimal changes are that are necessary in order to avoid re-creating the stream, then I have to answer: I don't know. However, it seems like your approach is overly complicated. The chain of `map`, `collect`, `filter`, `distinct` and `collect` that is built there is really hard to understand.

After a short rant...

> Maybe my fear that future Java programs will all look like this, and thus become completely unmaintainable is not justified. Maybe one just has "to get used to" this programming style. Maybe there's a short period when people are too eager with using the new language features, and it will come back to a "normal" style (and a "healthy" level of functional elements) sooner or later. But I, personally, think that a method like `createBsByMergingTheValuesOfAs()` would be sufficient and appropriate here.

... I'd like to suggest using a dedicated `Collector`, which already offers much of the infrastructure for mutable reduction that you seem to be emulating with this chain of operations:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class StreamCollectTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<A> listOfA = Arrays.asList(
            new A(1L, "A1", "V1"), 
            new A(2L, "A2", "V1"), 
            new A(1L, "A1", "V2"));

        Map<Long, B> result = listOfA.stream().collect(
            Collectors.toConcurrentMap(

                // The "id" will be the key of the map
                a -> a.getId(), 

                // The initial value stored for each key will be a "B"
                // whose set of values contains only the element of 
                // the corresponding "A"
                a -> new B(a.getId(), a.getName(), 
                    new LinkedHashSet<String>(Collections.singleton(a.getVal()))),

                // Two "B"s with the same key will be merged by adding
                // all values from the second "B" to that of the first
                (b0,b1) -> { b0.values.addAll(b1.values); return b0; }));

        System.out.println(result);
    }

    static class A
    {
        private final Long id;
        private final String name;
        private final String val;

        A(Long id, String name, String val)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.val = val;
        }

        public Long getId()
        {
            return id;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }

        public String getVal()
        {
            return val;
        }
    }

    static class B
    {
        private final Long id;
        private final String name;
        private final Set<String> values;

        B(Long id, String name, Set<String> values)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.values = values;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return id+","+name+","+values;
        }
    }
}
```

It prints

```
{1=1,A1,[V1, V2], 2=2,A2,[V1]}
```

So the `values()` of the resulting map should be exactly what you are looking for.